# Can't locate YAML/Tiny.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, yaml, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run a makefile used by my company, when I type 'make' in my shell I get this error:

> Can't locate YAML/Tiny.pm in @INC (you may need to install the YAML::Tiny module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at ./yaml-html.pl line 21.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./yaml-html.pl line 21.

And when I run:

> sudo cpan install YAML::Tiny

I get:

> Reading '/Users/altiire/.cpan/Metadata'
>     Database was generated on Thu, 13 Aug 2015 04:41:02 GMT
>   YAML::Tiny is up to date (1.69).

I'm on OS X Yosemite

Comment: `sudo cpan YAML::Tiny`

Comment: @serenesat: That is identical to `sudo cpan install YAML::Tiny`, which the OP has already tried

Comment: `cpan install <modulename>` works fine. It's not that that's the problem. I would suggests - run `perl -v` and `which cpan` to check you're using the same `perl` installation as `make`.

Comment: Your makefile is using a different installation of perl from the default one. You should try to locate that installation if you don't know where it is already

Comment: `perl -v
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

`which cpan
/opt/local/bin/cpan`

Comment: @Borodin and do you know how I can make it use the right installation of perl?

Comment: `cpan install Foo` will install the [install package](https://metacpan.org/pod/install) :)

Comment: @Altiire: You presumably have the default perl in your PATH. You need to change it so that it points to the correct perl

Comment: doing `export PERL5LIB=/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/` doesn't change anything am I doing it wrong? I'm downloading debian 8.1 right now to get my problem rounded